# ¿como obtener la ultima actualización de datos de un usuario con grails 3.8?

Tags: grails, groovy

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Grails 3.8. tengo algunos formularios que guardan datos de los usuarios, cuando estos datos se guardan en la BD pueden ser modificados, en la tabla usuarios tengo un campo actualización que en un principio decidí agregar para capturar en que momento se actualizaba algún tipo de datos, solo que ahora no encuentro de la forma de obtener esa fecha para después poder mostrarla, aunque obteniendo esa fecha lo segundo ya es mas fácil. No tengo nada de ese código hasta el momento pero creo que necesito darme una idea

Answer (score 0):

Si la fecha que comentas fue correctamente insertada en la última modificación, debes poder obtenerla simplemente obteniendo el Usuario que desees consultar, ya sea a partir del 'id' o alguna de las propiedades de tu clase de dominio.

Suponiendo que el 'id' del usuario a consultar es 10:

```
def usuario = Usuario.get(10)
def fechaActualizacion = usuario.actualizacion
```

O, asumiendo una búsqueda por alguna propiedad única que tengas, por ejemplo 'RFC':

```
def usuario = Usuario.findByRFC("ASDF900909LI2")
def fechaActualizacion = usuario.actualizacion
```

---

Por cierto, este comportamiento de guardar la fecha de creación y modificación lo puede hacer Grails automáticamente por ti. Solamente es necesario que en tus domains agregues las propiedades de este modo y Grails se encargará de setear sus valores en cada guardado o edición.

```
def dateCreated
def lastUpdated
```

Más sobre esto aquí: http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#eventsAutoTimestamping